# redux-form initialValues not populating

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

The form doesn't seem to fill the fields with their corresponding model attributes. State already has `selectedUser` by the time it's triggered so it's not something that would get fixed by the `enableReinitialize` setting

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { editUser } from '../actions'

class UserDetailsEdit extends React.Component {  
  renderField(field) {
    const { meta: { touched, error } } = field
    const className = `form-group ${touched && error ? 'has-danger' : ''}`

    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <label>{field.label}</label>
        <input 
          className="form-control"
          type="text"
          {...field.input}
        />
        <div className="text-help">
          {touched ? error : ''}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
        <Field 
          label="First Name"
          name="firstName"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <Field
          label="Last Name"
          name="lastName"
          component={this.renderField}
        />

        <div className="btn-toolbar" aria-label="...">
          <button className="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

UserDetailsEdit = reduxForm({
  form: 'UserDetailsEdit'
})(UserDetailsEdit)

UserDetailsEdit = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: state.selectedUser.data
  }),
  { editUser }
)(UserDetailsEdit)

export default UserDetailsEdit
```

### My console output:

[image]

### Data Object:

[image]

Comment: What does the data object look like?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the state object

Answer (score 0):

I think what's missing is the level you're using the spread operator on.

```
<input className="form-control" type="text" {...field.input} />
```

should be...

```
<input {...field} className="form-control" type="text" />
```

Comment: I don't have the code in front of me but from memory, value is on the field object, not the input property

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I get console error when I do what you're suggesting. Even using the exact sample code from the docs it doesn't populate

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. Turned out to be an issue in the reducer. It was essentially never "hooked" up

Comment: Good work, was about to suggest that it might be something somewere else. The code you had looked like it should work